# RxJava Observable with last state

Tags: java, rx-java, observable, frp, rx-swift

I’m starting with RxJava, and I would like to create an observable that can save the last state…

In RxSwift, that would be Variable (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#variables), but I can’t found an equivalente in RxJava…

I found a work around but it’s a lot of boiler plate code

```
private boolean isGettingCompanies = false;

public boolean isGettingCompanies() {
    return isGettingCompanies;
}

private void setIsGettingCompanies(boolean isGettingCompanies) {
    this.isGettingCompanies = isGettingCompanies;
    isGettingCompaniesPublishSubject.onNext(isGettingCompanies);
}

private final PublishSubject<Boolean> isGettingCompaniesPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

public Observable<Boolean> isGettingCompaniesPublishSubject() {
    return isGettingCompaniesPublishSubject.asObservable();
}
```

the RxSwift equivalent is this

```
private(set) var isGettingCompanies: Variable = Variable(false)
```

Can you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*BehaviorSubject* has a *value()* method which returns it's current value

```
final BehaviorSubject<Boolean> subject = BehaviorSubject.<Boolean>create(false);
final Boolean value = subject.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for :)
If you allow me one more question. 
Is there any way of subscribe to this BehaviorSubject, receive his last value and the continue to receive the next events?

Comment: You could use the replay operator (with capacity set to 1).